# iOS game and Facebook game: same app id?

Tags: facebook

I have built a game for iOS that uses Facebook Connect, and I will be making a Facebook version of the same game. Do I use the same applciation ID for both games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you would use the same app id for both games. In the "basic" tab of your app settings you specify what formats your application will be used on. This means you won't have to bug your users to authenticate 2 different apps (I'm assuming you might want them to use both versions).

Answer (score -1):

Right how it is now, you can't do that from the app management screen. Or at least for website app and facebook app is impossible to use same app id (you have to put the url for website)

Comment: You can specify in the app settings exactly what formats you want your app available on. Why would you want users to authenticate multiple times to use your app on different devices. Each one just has specific settings that you need to set